# Getting headers and status-code from Volley?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, http-headers, android-volley

Given any arbitrary volley request, how do I capture response headers and statusCode, regardless of success/failure?

Attempts/ideas:

- `JsonResponseRequest` ([gist](https://gist.github.com/AlecTaylor/e1fbc2c1545b5a48557ca5b6b677e428), minor [edit of this](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/issues/83#issuecomment-127554054))
- Tried following [Accessing all response headers](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/volley-users/rNTlV-LORzY) on volley-users from 2013, including github repo: [android-volley/add_response_headers](https://github.com/selecsosi/android-volley/tree/add_response_headers)
- Investigated use of `getHeaders`, but that seems to be just for requests
- [`GsonRequest`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) example from the Android tutorial
- [`ServerStatusRequestObject`](http://www.b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/getting-a-server-response-status-200-from-android-volley-library/) blog post

  - Perhaps there's some way of rewriting this to return a tuple of `response.data`, headers and `response.statusCode`?

:

```
@Override
protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    return Response.success(response.statusCode,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}
```

---

Edit: to clarify, I've got a simple `tuple` class:

```
public final class ErrResStatusHeaders<E, R> {
    public final E error;
    public final R result;
    public final int statusCode;
    public final Map<String, String> headers;
```

And in my `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected ErrResStatusHeaders<String,JSONObject> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // futures instantiated and utility function(s) called here

[...]

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final ErrResStatusHeaders<String,JSONObject> er_res)
```

Example utility function signature:

```
public ErrResStatusHeaders<String, JSONObject> register_or_login(
                                 final HashMap<String, String> data,
                                 final RequestFuture<JSONObject> register_future,
                                 final RequestFuture<JSONObject> login_future) {
```

Comment: Would be great if it worked regardless of `JSONObject` or `String` or no body (i.e.: any other http method), and that allows for use with `RequestFuture` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = "http://whatevergoeshere.com";
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("uri", responseListener, errorListener) {
    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Headers size:" + response.headers.size());
        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        if (volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.headers != null)
            Log.d("TEST", "Headers size:" + volleyError.networkResponse.headers.size());
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }
};
```

Well, looks like the question changed quite a bit so here's my edited answer:

You can use a custom Request subclass like this:

```
public class RawRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;

    /**
     * Creates a new GET request.
     *
     * @param url URL to fetch the string at
     * @param listener Listener to receive the String response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors
     */
    public RawRequest(String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this(Method.GET, url, listener, errorListener);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new request with the given method.
     *
     * @param method the request {@link Method} to use
     * @param url URL to fetch the string at
     * @param listener Listener to receive the String response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors
     */
    public RawRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                         Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        return Response.success(response, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Then use it in another class:

```
String uri = "http://whatevergoeshere.com";
RequestFuture<NetworkResponse> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
RawRequest rawRequest = new RawRequest("uri", future, future);
```

But the downside here is obviously now you have to parse the whole response by yourself. You *could* avoid that by writing a custom listener interface that passes the parsed response (be it JSON or String, or image) as well as the headers as a second argument. Then you'd have to write your own RequestFuture class to support this.

Honestly, though I would suggest trying another approach outside of an AsyncTask for this. Volley can already process the requests asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do this so it works in the `onPostExecute` callback in my activity? - The Volley stuff is running in `doInBackground`, specifically in a utility class that is invoked in the `return` there. So I need someway of getting the network response for all requests. Whether unrolled normally or via a future.

Comment: Updated the answer but I would really suggest changing the whole approach instead of using volley inside AsyncTask.

Comment: Via phone but from a glance that looks like ['ServerStatusRequestObject'](http://www.b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/getting-a-server-response-status-200-from-android-volley-library). However your idea of writing a new 'RequestFuture' et al. seems to be sound. Will test it out when I get back.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a whole bunch of the related files can't be extended outside the files themselves. So I'd probably end up forking `com.android.volley` and preparing a PR for Google. Might do that some other time, in the meantime will stop using Volley.

Comment: If my answer answered your question, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: The solution still hasn't presented itself. I've switched to OkHttp in the meantime.